# How do i fix this operational error in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, view, django-forms, django-views

I created a comment view in my views.py, for the user to write and submit comments through a form. The comments will be displayed on the same template the info regarding a movie is shown.

When I try to enter one of the films i get this error:

OperationalError at /myapp2/2/
no such column: myapp2_comentario.pelicula_id

views.py

```
def detallesPelicula(request, pelicula_id):
peliculas = get_list_or_404(Pelicula.objects.order_by('titulo'))
pelicula = get_object_or_404(Pelicula, pk=pelicula_id)
actor = get_list_or_404(Actor.objects)

comentarios = Comentario.objects.filter(pelicula=pelicula).order_by('fecha')
comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

if request.method == 'POST':
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        comentario = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        comentario.usuario = request.user
        comentario.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(pelicula.get_absolute_url())


context = {'pelicula': pelicula, 'peliculas': peliculas, 'comentarios':comentarios,'comment_form':comment_form}
return render(request, 'detallesPelicula.html', context)
```

my models.py

```
class Comentario(models.Model):
usuario = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
pelicula =models.ForeignKey(Pelicula, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True,blank=True)
texto = models.TextField(max_length=2000, default="")

def __str__(self):
    return self.usuario.nickname
```

forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comentario
    fields = ['texto']
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to make/apply *migrations*.

Comment: I made the migrations and the error keeps coming up.

Comment: did you migrate? So applied the migrations to the database?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59338581/how-do-i-fix-this-error-in-my-comments-view-in-my-django-app/59341017